# Combine Espresso and Room test

Tags: android-room, android-alertdialog, android-espresso

I'm currently creating some unit test for my app and currently learning about Espresso. I wanted to test an `AlertDialog` which adds something to a `Room` database though a `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` is fetched from the parent `Activity`. I wanted to know if combining or maybe just chaining the test for those things are possible to know that something was actually added to the database. I can't seem to find anything for that use-case.